# How to find span inside e element with title contains in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just wandering, how can I find span inside e element with title contains in `jQuery`?

Example:
I have the following html code:

```
<span class="test">
    <e title="1.2 testone">1</e>
    <e title="2.2 testtwo">2</e>
    <e title="3.3 testthree">3</e>
</span>
```

how can I find the e element object with title "two"?

Following is the `jQuery` code that I have been using, but doesn't seem working  :

```
$('span.test').children().find("2.2").addClass("foundYou")
```

Comment: The question should be how can I find `e` element inside span.

Comment: Why should an invalid CSS selector (like `"2.2"`) find anything?

Comment: add something to 2.2 to like c1.2 , c2.2 and c3.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
$('span.test').find("e[title=two]").addClass("foundYou")
```

```css
.foundYou{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">
<e title="one">1</e>
<e title="two">2</e>
<e title="three">3</e>
<e title="two">2</e>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selection:

```js
$("[title='two']").addClass("foundYou");
```

```css
.foundYou {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<span class="test">
<e title="one">1</e>
<e title="two">2</e>
<e title="three">3</e>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `two` will search for a tag with name `two`, for checking attribute use attribute equals selector. Although you have to use `filter()` method to filter among a collection.

```
$('span.test').children().filter('[title="two"]').addClass("foundYou")
```

Or use it with `children()` method.

```
$('span.test').children('[title="two"]').addClass("foundYou")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector string `span.test > e[title="two"]'`:

```js
$('span.test > e[title="two"]').addClass('found');
```

```css
.found {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">
<e title="one">1</e>
<e title="two">2</e>
<e title="three">3</e>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use descendent operator (`>`)

```js
console.log($('span.test>[title=two]'))
$('span.test>[title=two]').addClass('FoundYou')
```

```css
.FoundYou {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">
<e title="one">1</e>
<e title="two">2</e>
<e title="three">3</e>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<span class="test">
    <e title="one">1</e>
    <e title="two">2</e>
    <e title="three">3</e>
</span>

<script>
    console.log($(".test > e[title=two]").text())
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although here are already wonderful answers, but I would like to remind that if you want to select an element(s) by part of title text just like what is in your question you can use [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

If so use `[title *= '2.2']` instead of `[title = '2.2 testtwo']`

```js
$("[title *= '2.2']").addClass("foundYou");
```

```css
.foundYou {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<span class="test">
    <e title="1.2 testone">1</e>
    <e title="2.2 testtwo">2</e>
    <e title="3.3 testthree">3</e>
</span>
```